# why $(im(T^*))^{\perp}=KerT$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T: V \rightarrow V$ linear transformation in finite dimension

why is it true that $(im(T^*))^{\perp}=KerT$

and what does even $im(T^*)$ means?

Comment: Is $V$ finite dimensional?

Comment: Yes, I will edit now

Comment: $T^* : V \rightarrow V$ is the adjoint operator to $T$  and $im(T^*)$ is just the image of $T^*$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint for the full definition and also a hint for the answer to your question.

Comment: Also,  $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb R$ and not over $\mathbb C$, right? The answer changes depending over which of these fields is $V$ taken.

Comment: they didn't given wich field is